# Trying to make a hangman game but stuck in a loop?

Tags: python-3.x

I am not sure what I am doing wrong in my hangman game. I am trying to say if the guesses are less than 3 then stop the if loop. However it seems that once the if loop runs it will only run once more before just stopping for some reason. I know there is an error in the tries variable, when i print it after the loop runs its already at 3

```
import random

random_words = ['cat', 'human', 'corona', 'grouch', 'milk', 'welfare', 'dog', 'funny']

select_word = random.choice(random_words)
tries = 0

guess_letter = input('Guess a letter: ')

while tries < 3:
    if guess_letter == select_word[0]:
        x = guess_letter
        guess_letter = input(f'Guess another letter: {x} ')
    else:
        tries += 1
```

Comment: it is guessing a letter or a word?

Comment: Hint: when do you change what `guess_letter` is?

Comment: How are you restricting user from guessing more than one letter when you accept input for `guess_letter` ? You need to do a check to see if the user entered a letter and not a number. Are you trying to write code that gives user only 3 options?  Also, you are always checking the letter against the first character in the `select_word`. You need to check for the occurrence in any place. For ex: if the word is `human`, i can type `a`. It is part of the word, you need to check for that. Try `in` instead of `==` for your if statement